# Compact CSS code in Espresso

Tags: macos, text-editors

I like my CSS code each class / id in one single line, I hate how Espresso automatically adds 2 new lines after each curly bracket **{** I open while writing CSS. IS it possible to turn this off?

```
.class {
I'd rather have this on a single line
}
```

Comment: What is it you want? Something line `.class {  }`, so the contents are on the same line, as e.g. `.class { font-size: 15px; }` ? (ignoring the automatic comment line break)

Comment: yes, everything on the same line, please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/Applications/Espresso.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Sugars/CSS.sugar/TextActions/Actions.xml`, change

```
        <text-trigger key-equivalent="{"></text-trigger>
        <text>{
    $0
}</text>
```

to

```
        <text-trigger key-equivalent="{"></text-trigger>
        <text>{ $0 }</text>
```

Copying the sugar to Application Support would require a few additional steps, see [wiki.macrabbit.com/index/Override_default_sugars](http://wiki.macrabbit.com/index/Override_default_sugars/)